# best practice of adding a new property to a formGroup

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

What is the right way of adding a new object property to angular `formGroup`?

I have this set up:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    // store is the formGroupname
    store: this.fb.group({
      // branch and code are formControlName
      branch: ['asdf', Validators.required],
      code: ['asdf', Validators.required],
    }),
    selector: this.createStock({}),
    stock: this.fb.array([
      this.createStock({product_id: '1', quantity: 20}),
      this.createStock({product_id: '2', quantity: 30}),
      this.createStock({product_id: '3', quantity: 40}),
    ]),
  });
}
```

And inside the store property, I want to add if a checkbox is clicked. Upon reading on the angular documentation I have this solution that is working but giving me red line on vscode. I wonder is this the right way?

Solution:

```js
onSubmitForm() {

  // adding dynamic formgroup
  if(this.form.get('checkBoxStore').value)
  this.form.get('store').addControl(
    'foo',
    this.fb.group({
      testingAdd: this.form.get('test').value,
    })
  );
}
```

Image:

[image]
It's giving me an error message but working just fine. Weird but ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting that error because `FormGroup` extends `AbstractControl`, when you are using `get()` it is a type of `AbstractControl` so to resolve this you need to cast it as a `FormGroup`

```
(this.form.get('store') as FormGroup).addControl(...)
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ogrqir)

Answer (score 2):

You can typecast the abstractformcontrol as formgroup and store its mutable instance into a variable and perform the addcontrol operation like this:

```
const store: FormGroup = this.form.get('store') as FormGroup;
  store.addControl(
    'foo',
    this.fb.group({
      testingAdd: this.form.get('test').value,
    })
  );
```

Comment: If I want to add only foo control , then how?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? As in, you want to add "foo" formcontrol to the form or any prticular formgroup inside the form?

Comment: Only Foo formControl, like  store.addControl('foo': '')  it's throwing error

Comment: You can add it like this:

store.addControl('foo': new FormControl(''));

Comment: this: store.addControl('foo', new FormControl(''));  this is the solution

Comment: Welcome brother